# PostgreSQL Update Statement Performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a table with these columns:

```
id (int) 
col1 (int) 
col2 (varchar) 
date1 (date) 
col3 (int) 
cumulative_col3 (int)
```

and about 750k rows.

I want to update the `cumulative_col3` with the sum of `col3` of same `col1, col2` and previous to date of `date1`.

I have indexes on `(date1)`, `(date1, col1, col2)` and `(col1, col2)`.

I have tried the following query but it takes a long time to complete.

```
update table_name
set cumulative_col3 = (select sum(s.col3)
                       from table_name s
                       where s.date1 <= table_name.date1
                         and s.col1 = table_name.col1
                         and s.col2 = table_name.col2);
```

What can I do to improve the performance of this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to calculate the running sum in a derived table instead:

```
update table_name
  set cumulative_col3 = t.cum_sum
from (
  select id,
         sum(s.col3) over (partition by col1, col2 order by date1) as cum_sum
  from table_name
) s  
where s.id = table_name.id;
```

This assumes that `id` is the primary key of the table.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks, this worked and completed so far in just under a minute (50-58sec).

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, is it possible to re-write the derived table as a sub-query?, for a situation where one wants to do same in a database that does not support window functions at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding the following index to your table:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON table_name (date1, col1, col2, col3);
```

This index, if used, should allow the correlated sum subquery to be evaluated faster.

Comment: thanks for your response. unfortunately it didn't quite help. thanks again.

Comment: This suggestion can't work in this situation because we're doing a range scan on `date1`, putting it in front pretty much nixes the use of col1 and col2. Having `col3` in there makes it covering thus avoiding an extra fetch from the table, that I can understand.